# C++ void type - how?

Tags: c++, types, void

```
typedef void(Object Sender) TNotifyEvent;
```

This is what I'm trying to do from Delphi to C++, but it fails to compile with 'type int unexpected'.

The result should be something I can use like that:

```
void abcd(Object Sender){
  //some code
}

void main{
   TNotifyEvent ne = abcd;
}
```

How do I make such type(of type void)? I'm not very familiar with C++.

Comment: `void main()` is not standard C++.  `main()` always returns an `int`.

Comment: Are you trying to switch to C++Builder (and use the same TObject and TNotifyEvent types as Delphi), or are you trying to set up event handlers in straight C++ with a design that's similar to Delphi's?

Comment: Was trying to implement the TTimer class from Delphi to VC++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to define the type of a function that takes an Object as parameter and returns nothing, the syntax would be:

```
typedef void TNotifyEvent( Object Sender );
```

EDIT, as answer to the comment.

Yes, you can define the type of a function, and that type can later be used in different contexts with different meanings:

```
TNotifyEvent func;          // function declaration (weird as it might look)
                            // same as: void func( Object Sender );
TNotifyEvent *fp = func;    // function pointer declaration -- initialized with &func
void func( Object Sender )  // cannot use the type when defining the function
{}
void foo( TNotifyEvent f ); // compiler translates to TNotifyEvent * f
                            // just as 'int a[5]' is converted to 'int *a' 
                            // in function parameter lists.
```

Comment: um... Can that be used?  C++ can't have a type that's a function, just a pointer to a function, right?

Comment: I wonder what the problem is with the question --and hence the downvote. @James Curran, yes you can.

Comment: Actually, it can. There are function types in C++, there are just no variables of function types. But eg. what you put as an argument for std::function are actually function types. See here: http://ideone.com/fsn3O and here http://ideone.com/s8oY9

Answer (score 4):

Do you want a pointer to a function which takes an Object and returns nothing?

```
 typedef void (*TNotifyEvent)(Object Sender);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, because there is no common "object" class in C++. What you probably want there is a callback (Looking at events...), for which you need a functor (a class overloading `operator()`) or a function pointer.

Here's an example using the function pointer:

```
typedef void (*TNotifyEvent)(void *sender);
```

Comment: You can define an Object class, and have your other classes inherit from it.  It's not idiomatic C++, but you can do it.  It won't cover any system-defined or outside classes, of course.